# sql scheduler to update balance leaves

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, scheduler

This is my credit leave table.

```
creditleaveid   empid   creditleavemonth    creditedleaves
1               21      March                1
```

I am using scheduler to insert next month to credit/balance leave in this table is

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT creditleavemonth
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MONTH
STARTS '2017-02-01 00:00:00'
DO 
BEGIN
 CALL spAddCreditLeaves;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

stored procedure spAddCreditLeaves is

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `attendance`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `spAddCreditLeaves`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spAddCreditLeaves`()
BEGIN
INSERT INTO creditleaves(empid,creditleavemonth)SELECT empid,MONTHNAME(CURDATE())FROM empdetails;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now I want to update a record of inserted month by checking previous month's record for every employee. How to do that?

Comment: your `creditleaves` table does not seem to have the `year` field. don't you think it is required?

Comment: yes... I am going to modify it.

Comment: here what i want is when next scheduler is run... that time I want to update that inserted record... credit leave if 0 then it should be 1 if it is 1 then it should be incremented

Comment: #Ravinder Reddy... I added year column... please give me solution on my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my answer. It is working awesomely. stored procedure-

```
USE `attendance`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `spAddCreditLeaves`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spAddCreditLeaves`()
BEGIN
IF MONTHNAME(CURDATE())='January'
THEN
INSERT INTO creditleaves(empid,creditleavemonth,creditmonthyear,creditedleaves) SELECT empid,MONTHNAME(CURDATE()),YEAR(CURDATE()),creditedleaves+1 FROM creditleaves WHERE empid IN (SELECT empid FROM empdetails GROUP BY empid) AND creditedleaves IN(SELECT creditedleaves FROM creditleaves WHERE creditleavemonth=MONTHNAME((CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AND creditmonthyear=YEAR((CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 YEAR)));
ELSE
INSERT INTO creditleaves(empid,creditleavemonth,creditmonthyear,creditedleaves) SELECT empid,MONTHNAME(CURDATE()),YEAR(CURDATE()),creditedleaves+1 FROM creditleaves WHERE empid IN (SELECT empid FROM empdetails GROUP BY empid) AND creditedleaves IN(SELECT creditedleaves FROM creditleaves WHERE creditleavemonth=MONTHNAME((CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AND creditmonthyear=YEAR(CURDATE()));
END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```